# Binary serialization in c#: result size and performance

Tags: c#, serialization, xsd

I'm trying to understand and to decide the best approach to my problem.
I've an xsd that represents the schema of the information that I agreed with a client.

Now, in my application (c#, .net3.5) I use and consume an object that has been deserialized from an xml created according to the xsd schema.

As soon as I fill the object with data, I want to pass it to another application and also store it in a db. I have two questions:

1. I'd like to serialize the object to pass quickly to the other application: is better binary or xml serialization?
2. Unfortunately in the db I have a limited sized field to store the info, so I need a sort of compression of the serialized object. Binary serialization creates smaller data then xml serialization or I need in any case to compress this data? if yes, how?

Thanks!

Comment: 'Better' depends on your needs. binary-serialization is smaller and faster than xml-serialization but xml-files can be read and changed manually. Only you can answer the question if you have to compress your data. You are the only one who knows the size of your objects. Here is a class that you can use for compression: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx

Comment: If your application is already using xml serialisation for these objects then it would seem to be the best plan to do that. To properly answer your question though we'd need to know, among other things, how large these objects are (eg length of XML file generated when serialising), how far away the other app that you want to pass to is (ie what your bandwidth between the machines is) and if you have performance requirements for fetching and storing to the database (since compression will by its nature take time to do on the way in and out.

Comment: You say you have a "limited size field" to store the information - what data type is the field? If it's a string field then you'll potentially struggle to store binary data in there...

Comment: @user1567896: thanks! have the object in memory, and in the moment beofre store it on the db I want the fastest and with the smaller output. In this case binary according to your reply

Comment: @DanPuzey: unfortunately it is a string field, and after the binary representation is done, I have (in a way or in another) to transform it in a string representation (and after also string->object again)

Comment: @Chris: I use xsd *contract*, so the object is easily represented as xml, but to send to other application and to store in db I think (also according to your replies) is better to think about a binary representation

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to serialize the object to pass quickly to the other application: is better binary or xml serialization?

Neither is specific enough; binary can be good or bad; xml can be good or bad. Generally speaking binary is smaller and faster to process, but changing to such will be unusable from code that expects xml.

> Binary serialization creates smaller data then xml serialization or I need in any case to compress this data?

It *can* be smaller; or it *can* be larger; indeed, compression can make things smaller or larger too.

If space is your primary concern, I would suggest running it through something like protobuf-net (a binary serializer without the versioning issues common to `BinaryFormatter`), and then *speculatively* try compressing it with `GZipStream`. If the compressed version is smaller: store that (and a marker - perhaps a preamble - that says "I'm compressed"). If the compressed version gets bigger than the original version, store the original (again with a preamble).

Here's a recent breakdown of the performance (speed and size) of the common .NET serializers: http://theburningmonk.com/2013/09/binary-and-json-serializer-benchmarks-updated/